# sending a file via post request

Tags: node.js, express

I want to send a file through a post request but i cant seem to get it to work, can anyone spot the problem ?

thanks in advance

```
router.post('/:matchId', (req, res) => {
    zed.makeSpecBatch(req.body).then(matchCmd => {
        fs.writeFile(`./matches/${req.params.matchId}.bat`, matchCmd, err => {
            if (err) console.log(err);
            res.sendFile(`${req.params.matchId}.bat`, {root: __dirname+'/../matches'})
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are writing into `./matches/${req.params.matchId}.bat` file but sending `__dirname+'/../matches'` directory which is incorrect. I think you need to use correct path

```
 __dirname+'/matches'
```

or

```
const path = require('path');


res.sendFile(`${req.params.matchId}.bat`, {root: path.join(__dirname, './matches')})
```

Comment: i can confirm the path in the original post is currect

Answer (score 0):

1. If you are sending a file like (image, audio and video, pdf etc.) then you have to fetch by req.files
2. In req.body you get only text and JSON data.
3. In req.files you get the complete object of a file

   ```
   router.post('/:matchId', (req, res) => {
    // check here
   var files = req.files;
   console.log(files);
    zed.makeSpecBatch(req.files.file.path).then(matchCmd => {
       fs.writeFile(`./matches/${req.params.matchId}.bat`, matchCmd, err => {
        if (err) console.log(err);
         res.sendFile(`${req.params.matchId}.bat`, {root: __dirname+'/../matches'})
       });
     });
   });
   ```

   > If I am not correct then please reply the correct answer.

Comment: i am creating the file based on the matchId coming from the body `fs.writeFile(`./matches/${req.params.matchId}.bat`, matchCmd, err =>` this function creates the file to be downloaded